# $E(X|X+Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are Binomial$(n, p)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

> If $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. random variables with $Binomial(n, p)$ distribution, calculate $E(X|X+Y)$.

**Attempt:**

To calculate the conditional expectation, obviously you first need to determine the conditional probability funtion. Let us denote $Z = X + Y$. Then $Z \sim Binomial(2n, p)$. Now we need to find $P_{X|Z}(x|z)$. By the definition of conditional probability, that is:

$$ \frac{P_{X, Z}(x, z)}{P_Z(z)} $$

The denominator is known. I'm having problem with determining the joint distribution, i.e., the numerator. Notice that $X$ and $Z$ are **not** independent (because $Z = X + Y$ so $Z$ depends on $X$), therefore the joint distribution is not the product of the marginals.

Anyway, I still tried to come up with the joint pmf, and I came up with this:

$$ P(X = x, Z = z) = P(\{X = x\} \cap \{Z = z\}) = P(X = x)P(Z = z)\mathbf{1}  $$

Where $\mathbf{1}$ is the indicator random variable that equals $1$ if $x$ and $z$ are in $\{0, 1, 2, 3, ...\}$

> **Official Answer**
>
> $$ \frac{X + Y}{2} $$

Comment: $E(X|X+Y)=\fra {X+Y} 2$ for any two i.i.d random variables $X$ and $Y$ with finite mean. This follows by a symmetry argument and we don't need any particular distribution for this.

Comment: Note: $X,Z$ are dependent, but $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and $Y=Z-X$ so.. $$\mathsf P(X{=}x,Z{=}z)~{=\mathsf P(X{=}x, Y{=}z{-}x)\\[1ex]=\mathsf P(X{=}x)\mathsf P(Y{=}z{-}x)}$$  (But, yes using the symmetry argument is *much* easier.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible approach though not the most elegant. We first compute the distribution of $X\mid X+Y=m$ for $m=0,\dotsc, 2n$. To this end note that by the definition of conditional probability 
$$
P(X=k\mid X+Y=m)=\frac{P(X=k, X+Y=m)}{P(X+Y=m)}=\frac{P(X=k)P(Y=m-k)}{P(X+Y=m)}\tag{0}
$$
where we used the equality of events $(X=k, X+Y=m)=(X=k, Y=m-k)$ and the independence of $X$ and $Y$ in the final equality. After a bit of simplification one finds that
$$
P(X=k\mid X+Y=m)=\frac{\dbinom{n}{k}\dbinom{n}{m-k}}{\dbinom{2n}{m}}; \quad (k=0,\dotsc, m)
$$
It follows that
$$
E(X\mid X+Y=m)=\binom{2n}{m}^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^m k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{m-k}\tag{1}.
$$
We claim that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^m k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{m-k}=\frac{m}{2}\binom{2n}{m}\tag{2}
$$
To do this we recognize that the LHS  of $(2)$ is the coefficient of $x^m$ in the product of $F(x)=nx(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom{n}{k}x^k$ and $G(x)=(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k$ (see [cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Convolution_(Cauchy_products))). But
$$
F(x)G(x)=nx(1+x)^{2n-1}
$$
whence by the binomial theorem the coefficient of $x^m$ in the product is $$n\binom{2n-1}{m-1}=\frac{n(2n-1)(2n-2)\dotsb(2n-1-m)}{(m-1)!}=m\frac{2
n(2n-1)(2n-2)\dotsb(2n-1-m)}{2m(m-1)!}$$
which equals $\frac{m}{2}\binom{2n}{m}$ as desired.

(1) and $(2)$ together imply that $E(X\mid X+Y=m)=\frac{m}{2}$ as desired.

**Addendum.** As pointed out in the comments. The above work is unnecessary. Note that
$$
E(X\mid X+Y)+E(Y\mid X+Y)=E(X+Y\mid X+Y)=X+Y
$$
and because $X$ equals in distribution to $Y$ and $X$ is independent of $Y$,
$$
E(X\mid X+Y)=E(Y\mid X+Y)
$$
from which the result follows.

Comment: The second solution is very elegant and clever, appreciate it. That sum in the first solution is very nasty.

Comment: For the equation (1), you could have noticed that this is a hypergeometric distribution with mean m/2 or use vandermonde identity.